# ES6 Express and static methods usage questions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs

I'm trying to learn express and wanted to use ES6 with babel. My questions is When I use static methods for handling requests like bellow ;

```
class MyCtrl {

   static index (req,res) {
        res.status(200).send({data:"json data"});
    }
}

router.get('/', MyCtrl.index)
```

I was wondering, will this(using static methods ) be effecting performance? I do not have much knowledge of Node.js runtime but as I know using static methods so often in some language (like C#) is not a good thing.

Or is there another proper way to doing this with ES6 classes .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 classes aren't really some new structure, it's just some syntax sugar for JavaScript's prototypal model.

So when you do something like this:

```
class Animal {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  static printAllowedTypes() {
    console.log('Rabbit, Dog, Cat, Monkey');
  }

  printName() {
    console.log(`Name: ${this.name}`);
  }

  printAge() {
    console.log(`Age: ${this.age}`);
  }
}
```

Behind the scenes, it basically just translates to this:

```
function Animal(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

Animal.printAllowedTypes = function() {
  console.log('Rabbit, Dog, Cat, Monkey');
};

Animal.prototype.printName = function() {
  console.log(`Name: ${this.name}`);
};

Animal.prototype.printAge = function() {
  console.log(`Age: ${this.age}`);
};
```

So it's a convenient shorthand, but it's still just using JavaScript's prototypal stuff. So as far as your question goes, all you're doing is passing a regular function to `router.get` so there isn't any performance difference.

Comment: Thanks. your answer makes sense.